# Combining files with 4 columns each, into 4 files for each column

Tags: command-line, sed, awk, perl, columns

So I have a bunch of text files which look like this:

> T1
> r1 a  b  c d
> r2 d e f g
> ...
>
> T2
> r1 h i j k
> r2 l m n o
> ...

And I want to make FOUR different text files in the following format:

> __ T1 T2 ...
> r1 a h ...
> r2 d l ...
>
> __ T1 T2 ...
> r1 b i ...
> r2 e m ...

So basically, I have a certain number of files. Each picks a TEMPERATURE and then runs over MAGNETIC FIELDs (T1... temp; r1,r2,.. magnetic field) and then the a,b,c,d etc are 4 different calculations, each column being its own. I want to be able to compile the FIRST column for each T (file) into a single file so I can copy it into excel, then compile the SECOND column for each T into a different file and do the same. If someone tells me how to put in the data so that it formats it exactly like my files I can detail my question more...

Comment: I want to make it where it is in the format to be plotted as a surface for each column (magnetic fields (r1,..) down the side, then the column FOR THAT CALCULATION, going across for each T value; I'm not sure if that helps explain it better or not...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming T1, T2 are the names of four input files:

Using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==1 { header = header " " FILENAME;
              next # we want to skip the first line
            }
            { rows[$1]; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) A[$1,i] = A[$1,i] " " $i }
        END { for(i=2;i<=5;i++) {
                printf("__%s\n", header);
                for(j in rows) printf("%s%s\n", j, A[j,i]);
              }
            }' T1 T2 T3 T4
```

This only creates a single output file, with all your desired tables concatenated. If you want to split it into four files, you'll have to do more work.

If you want to extract the header lines from the first line rather than the name of the input files, replace `FILENAME` with `$0`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm somewhat unfamiliar with using terminal/things like this. T1, T2 are actually the first line, or I was going to format the data to have an output like this:
> T1 r1 a b c d  //  
> T1 r2 e f g h  

Also, when I try to run that commmand I get an error: "awk: cmd. line:5:                 for(j in rows) printf("%s%s\n", j, A[j,i]
awk: cmd. line:5:                                                          ^ unexpected newline or end of string"

If I have the files in the above format is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can someone tell me how to input the data from my actual output file so it keeps its original spacing and everything? If I had that I could show you how I wanted it to come out and it might be easier to understand. Thank you guys!

Comment: Keeping original spacing is difficult with awk. It's possible but tends to be more complicated. There was a `)` missing in my code. I replaced it. And also adjusted code to skip first line in each of the four input files.